# how to aggregate time and data correspondingly using SQL?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I want to aggregate the time series and the data under each time series, the table I have now is:

```
00:00,00:15,location_1,300
00:00,00:15,location_2,240

00:15,00:30,location_1,100
00:15,00:30,location_2,60
```

What I want is:

```
00:00,00:30,location_1,400
00:00,00:30,location_2,300
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: And please post us your table definition.

Comment: The first two columns look like `time` columns - you can't add two `time` values (what is the sum of 3 O'clock and 6 O'clock?). It seems you rather want an `interval` there - if you change your table definition _then_ you can actually add the values. Given the current sample data it's simply not possible.

Comment: What if there's a gap in the time series? I'm guessing only contiguous time series should be aggregated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The question says "time series", so I interpreted it to mean "start time" and "end time" (calendar-style). In that case a range type such as `tsrange` would be a good data-type to use.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the fields are called start, stop,, name and peoples.

You will have the result you want with a query like this one

```
SELECT min(start), max(stop), name, sum(peoples) 
FROM rooms group by 3 order by 3;
```

Comment: What if there's a gap in the time series? I'm guessing only contiguous intervals should be aggregated.

Comment: So please could you describe your needs more precisely, with a schema and more reprentatve datas.